# Export the hidden div as PDF using jsPDF

Tags: javascript, html, jspdf, html2canvas

I am trying to create a PDF from html div content. The PDF generation is working fine expect from hidden div items.

Here is my hidden div

```
<div id="listview" style="display: none;">test</div>
```

And my PDF render scripts

```
var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
        var options = {
            background: '#fff'  
        };
        pdf.addHTML($('#listview')[0], options, function () {
                pdf.save('searchresult.pdf');
        });
```

The content on #listview will be appended dynamically. The PDF render throws below error

```
html2pdf.js:115 Uncaught Missing source element or string.
```

Thanks in advannce for the support

Comment: I am able to achieve with toggle on the hidden div item

Answer (score 0):

The item is resolved with toggle on the id. This post can be closed

```
$("#listview").toggle();
```